# jquery action from popup to document

Tags: jquery, popup

I have a question. I build my webapp, and i need to open poupup with buttons.
When user clicks on button app must change text in document (not in popup).

Anyone have a idea?

Comment: **-1** "I need a feature, Ideas?"

Comment: Too wide my friend, you'll need to give us something more specific to work on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pop up will still be a part of the document. You will hide the popup with css, and then on click on something you will open it like this

```
$('#yourpopupid').toggle();
```

Next, on click of the button in the popup you just change the content of another id or class on your page like this:

```
$('#yourmainpageidtobechanged').html('contenthere');
```

That's all!

Comment: But if i must do it in normal popup? Its any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Check

```
window.opener.getElementById('yourDivID').innerText = "Hello World";
```